# numpy 2D matrix- How to improve performance in this case?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I came to know that numpy is slow for individual element accesses for a very big matrix. The following part of the code takes about 7-8 minutes to run. Size of the Matrix is about 3000*3000

```
import numpy as np
................
................
ArrayLength=len(Coordinates)
AdjMatrix=np.zeros((len(Angles),len(Angles)))
for x in range(0, Arraylength):
    for y in range(x+1, Arraylength-x):
        distance=Distance(Coordinates[x],Coordinates[y)
            if(distance<=radius)
                AdjMatrix[x][y]=distance
                AdjMatrix[y][x]=distance
```

I am basically trying to construct an adjacency matrix for a graph that consists of about 3000 nodes. Can someone help me in doing this numpy way? Or any alternatives?

Edit: Here is the Distance() function

```
Def Distance(p1,p2):
    distance=np.sqrt(np.square(p1[0]-p2[0])+np.square(p1[1]-p2[1]))
    return distance
```

By the way I am passing coordinates as tuples.. As in p[0]=x-coordinate and p[1]= y- coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you post the `Distance()` function? If it's common function, `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` can calculate the distance matrix very quickly:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist

**Edit**:

You can use `pdist` indeed, here is an example:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
coordinates = [(0.0, 0), (1.0, 2.0), (-1.0, 0.5), (3.1, 2.1)]
dist = squareform(pdist(coordinates))
print dist
```

output:

```
[[ 0.          2.23606798  1.11803399  3.74432905]
 [ 2.23606798  0.          2.5         2.1023796 ]
 [ 1.11803399  2.5         0.          4.40113622]
 [ 3.74432905  2.1023796   4.40113622  0.        ]]
```

If you want to mask some data:

```
dist[dist > 3.0] = 0
print dist
```

output:

```
[[ 0.          2.23606798  1.11803399  0.        ]
 [ 2.23606798  0.          2.5         2.1023796 ]
 [ 1.11803399  2.5         0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          2.1023796   0.          0.        ]]
```

Comment: You can combine this with `AdjMatrix[AdjMatrix >= radius] = 0` to duplicate the above code, with no Python loops.

Comment: I have edited my question.please have a look. @mtrw Could you please elaborate? I am sorry.. I am not so familiar with python